# Do bonecharm traits stack?

Tags: dishonored-2

I've been searching for an answer to this question and the results have been mixed, some say it stacks, other say it doesn't, some say only some traits stack.  What is the actual answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They all stack** (which is also the purpose of and idea behind [*Trait Synergy*](https://dishonored.gamepedia.com/Trait_Synergy)).

There have been bugs, like with *Strong Arms*, where the effect would actually worsen and reverse, but (most of) these have been fixed with updates.

Of course, the same applies to Corrupted Charms, in which case an effect can diminish another or cancel it out (e.g. *Armored Bones* and *Zephyr*: reduced movement speed combined with increased movement speed).

Comment: You are right, I made a double choke speed charm and I definitely notice a speed increase.